# Loop While ... Error

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm creating a tool to modify the rows and columns of a data table based on a couple of inputs: Min, Step-up and Max. Min value (I9) links to K6. I would like every cell below K6 to increase according the Step-up value (I10), until the values in K reach the Max value (I11). I'm having trouble terminating the loop based on the maximum value.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub Button3_Click()

Dim x As Integer

Dim z As Integer

Do
    Cells((8 + z), 11).Value = Cells(((7 + z)), 11).Value + Cells(10, 9).Value
        z = z + 1
        x = Cells((8 + z), 11).Value
        Loop While x < Cells(11, 9).Value


End Sub
```

[Link to Spreadsheet Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGvzg.png)

Comment: `the Max value (I10)` ... then in the code `x < Cells(11,9).Value`. This is inconsistent. Perhaps you mean `Cells(10,9)`

Comment: Thanks for the catch! I edited the original post: I meant I9 (Min), I10 (Step-up), I11 (Max)

Answer (score 1):

You set value of `x` after changing value of `z`. That means you always check a value from empty cell, one cell below last modified. This should be fine:

```
Sub Button3_Click()

Dim x As Integer

Dim z As Integer

Do
    Cells((8 + z), 11).Value = Cells(((7 + z)), 11).Value + Cells(10, 9).Value
        x = Cells((8 + z), 11).Value
        z = z + 1
        Loop While x < Cells(11, 9).Value


End Sub
```

As a side note, I don't know if your are working with percentages or is this just a format, but consider using `Double` to properly take values of numbers lower than 1.

And one more thing I found while testing. For some reason VBA thinks that 1 < 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, the fix worked. I noticed that the values in the rows and columns continued past the max value, as the code read 'stop once value past the max' rather than 'stop just before reaching the max'.

I modified it as follows - adding a similar segment of code for the row dimension at the top of the table.

```
Sub Button3_Click()

Dim x As Double

Dim z As Double

Dim w As Double

Dim y As Double

Do
    Cells((8 + z), 11).Value = Cells((7 + z), 11).Value + Cells(10, 9).Value

        x = Cells((8 + z), 11).Value

        z = z + 1

        Loop While x <= Cells(11, 9).Value - Cells(10, 9).Value

Do
    Cells(6, (13 + y)).Value = Cells(6, (12 + y)).Value + Cells(10, 6).Value

        w = Cells(6, (13 + y)).Value

        y = y + 1

        Loop While w <= Cells(11, 6).Value - Cells(10, 6).Value


End Sub
```